# Using the Modula-3 mode from CM3 I get "Package cl is deprecated". Any replacement?

Tags: cl

I get the message that "Package cl is deprecated" when trying to use the Modula 3 mode from git@github.com:modula3/cm3.git.
The file in question is https://github.com/modula3/cm3/blob/master/m3-tools/gnuemacs/src/modula3.el

Is there any replacement? A workaround?

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a URL for the file in question, so whoever is trying to help you could find the file without having to wade through the whole project (or, as I did, cloning the repo so I could search it more efficiently). If you make it easy for people to help you, I think you will get more and better help.

Comment: Find out if the latest Module 3 mode needs `cl.el`. If so, go ahead and ignore the warning. Deprecation does not mean `cl.el` is not supported. Let the maintainers of Module 3 know, and they can update their code to adapt to using `cl-lib.el` or whatever is really needed. It's not your problem - it's theirs. And this is only if in fact the latest Module 3 code still really needs `cl.el`. And +1 to what @NickD said (but it's orthogonal to what I've said).

Comment: @Drew, my question was more in the line of what needs to be done to update said file. Point taken,